# Orthogonal projection matrix eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $P$ be $n\times n$ orthogonal projection matrix. Suppose $x$ is an $n$ dimensional unit vector which belongs to the range space of $P$. Now, I want to show the following holds:$$Px=x.$$This equality says that one of the eigenvalues is $1$. Showing this easy because if we let eigenvector of this system $v$ then:$$Pv=\lambda v\implies PPv=\lambda Pv\implies Pv=\lambda ^2v\implies \lambda v=\lambda ^2v,$$which yields $\lambda _{1,2}=0,1$, because for an orthogonal projection matrix we know that $P^2=P$. On the other hand, I'm not sure how to show that $x$ is indeed an eigenvector.

Comment: Recall: an eigenvector of $P$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ satisfies $Px = \lambda x$. So, showing $Px = x$ (where $x \neq 0$) is the very definition of an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: But the statement says that this eigenvector must be exactly x which is not an ordinary vector. For example if $x$ wasn't in the range space of $P$ then would be the answer the same?

Comment: There's nothing special about the eigenvector, except that it has length $1$. For projection matrices, the range is exactly equal to the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda = 1$. Any such eigenvector $x$ is in the range, as $x = Px \in \operatorname{range} P$. Berci's argument shows the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any - not necessarily orthogonal - projection (i.e. *idempotent*) matrix satisfies this:

If $x$ is in the range of $P$ then $x=Py$ for some $y$, thus
$$x\ =\ Py\ =\ P^2y\ =\ Px\,.$$